# Read JSON Data with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json

I am making an app using Swift and want to read JSON data from a URL, since swift doesn't JSON ideally I found a tool called swiftyJSON, which makes reading JSON from a URL work so well. Anyways enough background here is the JSON.

```
{
"acstate" : 1,
"current_user" : [
  {
   "email" : null,
   "name_last" : "Salli",
   "uid" : "57",
   "name_first" : "John",
   "pass" :      "$2y$10$DnU1tiSFiqJ5xt9zZHPKW.FYLPq4sSklhY7CQSIM6feNmfpJguOLC",
      "initemail" : "john.salli@gmail.com"
  }
],
    "uid" : "57"
}
```

I am able to use the code

```
let currentUID = readableJSON["uid"]
```

This code works great and I am able to read the UID
However when I I want to find the users name I am not able too

```
let currentUserName = readableJSON["name_first"]
```

With that code all I get is Null

I have also tried

```
let currentUserName = readableJSON["current_user","name_first"]
```

What is wrong with this code and not letting me get all the data I need

Comment: Try "current_user. name_first"

Comment: @kdogisthebest that is NOT working

Comment: Oh sorry I didn''t realize that you have an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `name_first` the notation is like accessing a property in Swift, so use:

```
let currentUserName = readableJSON["current_user[0].name_first"]
```

OR

```
let currentUserName = readableJSON["current_user"][0]["name_first"]
```

Comment: I didn't see that current_user is an array (It has square brackets then curly brackets). I'm not sure if your json is being returned correctly, but to remedy this just get the first item in the array